# Xamarin Forms MasterDetail Page with TabbedPage iOS [BUG]

Tags: debugging, xamarin.forms, master-detail, tabbedpage

I am using Xamarin Forms with Master Details Page and TabbedPage. There seems to be a bug that I cannot understand or fix. On the MasterDetail Page, at the bottom quarter of the page, no clickevents are being fired. In other words, that part of the screen seems unclickable. It works fine on Android but on all iOS devices, the bottom quarter of the MasterDetail Page (that is just above the Bottom Tab) seems Unclickable.

I tried removing all content from the page and just add a simple button in that area and that too didn't work. It really seems frustrating.

On simulator as well as real app deployment, it doesn't work.

Comment: try to create tabbed page in c# file and check weather its working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#populate-a-tabbedpage-with-a-page-collection.

Comment: I just write a demo to test on my side and it works well. Can you please share us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?